# Trying to compute age in groovy

Tags: date, groovy, grails

I have a date object that holds a persons birthday.  My code looks like:

```
def getAge(){
    //birthday, birthYear, birthMonth, birthDayOfMonth are class level properties
    def c= new GregorianCalendar(birthYear, birthMonth-1, birthDayOfMonth)
    birthday = c.time
    //What do I do now?
}
```

I need to return the age of the person.  How do I do that in Groovy?  The age only needs to be a integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just create one calendar with the current date and use the year to compute age:

```
def now = new GregorianCalendar()
def fake = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), birthMonth-1, birthDayOfMonth)
return now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - birthYear - (fake > now ? 1 : 0)
```

the fake date is used to understand if birthday is already passed in current year, if it's not then you must substract 1 to the difference between years..

Answer (score 4):

I know this is question is old, but it inspired me to create this function, working on dates:

```
static Integer calculateAge(Date birthday, Date offset = new Date()) {
   def birthdayThisYear = offset.clone().clearTime()
    birthdayThisYear[MONTH]= birthday[MONTH]
    birthdayThisYear[DATE] = birthday[DATE]

    offset[Calendar.YEAR] - birthday[Calendar.YEAR] - (birthdayThisYear > offset ? 1 : 0)
}
```

You can either call it with the birthday alone to calculate the age today, or with a second argument, being the date where you want to calculate the persons age.

Comment: +1; Note that if you use an older version of groovy, you will need to put `clearTime()` on a separate line, as that didn't return the date object until version 1.8 or so.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.metaClass.calculateAge = { Date offset = new Date() ->
        def birthdayThisYear = offset.clone().clearTime()
        birthdayThisYear[Calendar.MONTH]= delegate[Calendar.MONTH]
        birthdayThisYear[Calendar.DATE] = delegate[Calendar.DATE]
        return offset[Calendar.YEAR] - delegate[Calendar.YEAR] - (birthdayThisYear > offset ? 1 : 0)
    }
```

example of use:

```
def dateParser = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
dateParser.lenient = false

dateParser.parse('1980-02-23').calculateAge()
```